# Save Generated Random Numbers for later use

Tags: c#, random

This following code will get me a random number:

```
Random r = new Random();
int srandom = r.Next(2147483647);
```

I want to save it to a string/int/long or some how so I will be able to use the same number. So for example if I call srandom now I will get random number but after a while it will change. I would like it to stay the same.

Comment: Do you want a new random number every time the program starts (and use the same one until it quits), or do you want to generate it only once ever, and load the saved number the next time the program starts?

Comment: I would like a new random number every time the program starts (and use the same one until it quits)

Comment: Change the srandom as a static field of your class, and assign it from the static constructor of your class.

Comment: @SteveB I had static code saved int srandom to global static but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Globals8.GlobalInt8 = Globals8.GlobalInt8.HasValue ? Globals8.GlobalInt8 : srandom;
```

And you declare the variable GlobalInt8 as a nullable int like this:

```
public static class Globals8
{
    private static int? globalInt8 = default(int?);
    public static int? GlobalInt8 
    {
         get { return globalInt8;}
         set { globalInt8 = value;}
    }
}
```

The same thing can be applied to the long variable. What happens here that you initialize the value to the default value which is similar to null in reference object. After that you check if the variable has value then you ignore it. Else you set its value.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: hmm so just a sec this code will hold the only first random number? It will not call srandom everytime? I need once random generated number.

Comment: your code does not works. `default(int)` will return 0. So GlobalInt8.HasValue will be true. You have to initialize it with `null `instead, or use the correct type (`default(int?)`)

Comment: I don't understand what you really want to implement give me the sequence of calls or be clearer with your comment so I can tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a static field in your class, and initialize it once in the program lifecycle by setting it from the static constructor :

```
public class YourClass{

    private static readonly int g_RandomInt;

    static YourClass(){
        g_RandomInt = new Random().Next();    
    }

    public void InstanceMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(g_RandomInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, How should I set it and get it?

Comment: I could answer it, but I prefer advising you to take a good C# tutorial on the web. This is very basics of the C# language, and there are dozens of tutorials on the web. And to be honest, I can't answer you directly, as it depends on the whole program (which class is responsible for storing it, which class will consume it, etc.)